# Which punctuation marks are correctly used in this type of question/phrase

Tags: punctuation, commas, semicolons

I was asking a question and while formulating the content, I made the following sentence/phrase:

> What I am facing trouble with, is; referencing....

Is my usage of comma(`,`) and semi-colon(`;`) correct? Or is **<s>(one of?)</s>** the following usage correct:

> 1. What I am facing trouble with is; referencing    ## No comma after *what*
> 2. What I am facing trouble with; is; referencing    ## Semicolon after *what* and *is*
> 3. What I am facing trouble with, is, referencing    ## Comma after *what* and *is*

The entire sentence(currently) is

> What I am facing trouble with, is; referencing the `subfid` field in
>   `bsmsgs` to new id values in `buynsell` correctly referencing and stored
>   in `bns_id` of **replies** table.

Here is [the link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/39411/7775) to actual question.

Comment: Could you write a complete sentence example? I have an idea but I'm not sure about your usage of "referencing" along with what comes after that.

Comment: @user3169 Edited question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any punctuation in that sentence. (Well, okay, other than the period).

> What I am facing trouble with is referencing [x].

This doesn't feel like a fleshed out answer, but I'm not sure what else to add. A possible example of a full sentence with this construction could be:

> What I am facing trouble with is knowing when to speak and when to remain silent.
>
> What I am facing trouble with is learning how to spell words in other languages.

I'll also add that a more common way to phrase this would be:

> What I am *having* trouble with...

Although *facing* is perfectly acceptable.

---

Edited to respond to the updated example sentence you added. There is quite a lot wrong with that sentence, actually.  I've edited below to the best of my ability; please let me know if I've misinterpreted something.

> What I am facing trouble with is referencing the `subfid` field in `bsmsgs` to new id values in `buynsell` while correctly referencing and storing them in the `bns_id` field of the `replies` table.

Comment: Even if I want to stress more on the question following *is*?

Comment: Yes. If you want to be able to add punctuation to separate it, you can say "What I am having trouble with is ***this:*** referencing...".  Once you add the "this", you can use the semicolon to offset the clauses.

Answer (score 2):

I would rather say "I am facing trouble with […]." Keeping your phrasing, I would say "What I am facing trouble with is […]."

There isn't any need to put a comma before the verb, and I think a comma should never be put between the subject, and the verb (if not in the case of a parenthetical introduced by a comma).